# how does blktrace work?

Tags: linux, monitoring, block-device

I am trying to understand the Linux block layer so I am writing a blog about it: http://www.linuxintro.org/wiki/blktrAce. When calling blktrace like this:

```
blktrace -d /dev/sdg -o - | blkparse -i -
```

I see e.g. the output

```
8,96   4      695   430.080106382  2356  I   N 0 (00 ..) [kworker/4:2]
8,96   3       29   430.082179440    53  D   N 0 (00 ..) [ksoftirqd/3]
```

I do not understand what this means. According to the man page of blkparse, there is an RWBS field (containing R for read, W for write, B for barrier, D for discard or S for sync). With some experimenting I found out it is the 7th column. However it contains N. What does that mean? Where can I find the info what it means?

Answer (score 10):

It appears that there are additional undocumented flags in the RWBS field and that the 'B' for barrier is deprecated. N denotes anything that is not discard, read or write.

```
D - discard
W - write
R - read
N - None of the above 

F - FUA
A - readahead
S - sync
M - metadata



static inline void fill_rwbs(char *rwbs, struct blk_io_trace *t)
{
    int w = t->action & BLK_TC_ACT(BLK_TC_WRITE);
    int a = t->action & BLK_TC_ACT(BLK_TC_AHEAD);
    int s = t->action & BLK_TC_ACT(BLK_TC_SYNC);
    int m = t->action & BLK_TC_ACT(BLK_TC_META);
    int d = t->action & BLK_TC_ACT(BLK_TC_DISCARD);
    int f = t->action & BLK_TC_ACT(BLK_TC_FLUSH);
    int u = t->action & BLK_TC_ACT(BLK_TC_FUA);
    int i = 0;

    if (f)
            rwbs[i++] = 'F'; /* flush */

    if (d)
            rwbs[i++] = 'D';
    else if (w)
            rwbs[i++] = 'W';
    else if (t->bytes)
            rwbs[i++] = 'R';
    else
            rwbs[i++] = 'N';

    if (u)
            rwbs[i++] = 'F'; /* fua */
    if (a)
            rwbs[i++] = 'A';
    if (s)
            rwbs[i++] = 'S';
    if (m)
            rwbs[i++] = 'M';

    rwbs[i] = '\0';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`blkparse` documentation looks outdated and is missing to document this flag.

Its source code is lacking comments however, from this [function](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/axboe/blktrace.git/tree/blkparse_fmt.c#n53) it looks like `N` means the operation is neither a `read`, a `write`, a `discard`, or anything expected by the code, perhaps `N` is simply used for `None`.